# Flutter: Strange behavour of StreamProvider, widgets rebuilt with incomplete data

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am getting incomplete data from a StreamProvider.

The next minimum widget tree reproduces my problem: A SreamProvider over a Tabbed Screen.

My User object contains a map of several values (among other properties) and I use these values for one screen of the Tabbed View by calling `final user = Provider.of<User>(context);` inside the `build()` method in order to get these values in this screen whenever the app starts or is completely rebuilt (i.e. hot reload).

**The problem**: Whenever I switch tabs and go back to this tab, the `build()` method is called only once with `final user = Provider.of<User>(context);` returning an incomplete copy of User: some data is missing (some properties of a map inside the User object) and `build()` is never called again to complete the data (given that the StreamProvider should return the complete object at some point, possibly causing some rebuilds. The result: some data is missing and some widgets of the Screen cannot be built.

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);
    // return either Home or Authenticate widget:
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      return WelcomeScreen();
    } else {
      return StreamProvider<User>.value(
        value: FirestoreService(uid: firebaseUser.uid).user,
        child: TabsWrapper(),
      );
    }
  }
}


class TabsWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initialIndex;
  TabsWrapper({this.initialIndex: 0});

  @override
  _TabsWrapperState createState() => _TabsWrapperState();
}

class _TabsWrapperState extends State<TabsWrapper> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: widget.initialIndex,
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: lightBlue,
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          labelStyle: navi.copyWith(color: darkBlue),
          unselectedLabelColor: darkBlue,
          labelColor: darkBlue,
          indicatorColor: darkBlue,
          tabs: choices.map((TabScreen choice) {
            return Tab(
              text: choice.title,
              icon: Icon(choice.icon, color: darkBlue),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: <Widget>[
            FirstScreen(),
            SecondScreen(),
            ThirdScreen(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problematic Screen (FirstScreen):

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final TabController tabController;
  final User user;

  FirstScreen ();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print('**************************************** ${user.stats}');  //Here I can see the problem
    
    return SomeBigWidget(user: user);
  }
}
```

The print(${user.stats}) shows the incomplete map (stats) and the `build()` **is never called again** (with the remaining data) so the User object remains incomplete. It is only called twice (and the data returned with the complete object) when reloading or launching the app.

Any solution will be welcome!

PD: I found a simpler way to reproduce the situation. No need to change tabs:

Inside `FirstScreen()` I have a column of StatelessWidgets. If I call `Provider.of<User>(context)` within one of them I get an incomplete version of the object. The `user.stats` map has half of the key-value pairs that it has when accesing it through Provider.of some widgets above.

This is how the stream is updated from Firebase. (the object is created every time):

```
Stream<User> get user {
    Stream<User> userStream = usersCollection.document(uid).snapshots().map((s) => User.fromSnapshot(s));
   
    return userStream;
  }
```

I also have `updateShouldNotify = (_,__) => true;`

The User model:

```
class User {
  String uid;
  String name;
  String country;

  Map stats;

  User.fromUID({@required this.uid});


  User.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : uid = snapshot.documentID,
        name = snapshot.data['name'] ?? '',
        country = snapshot.data['country'] {
    try {
      stats = snapshot.data['stats'] ?? {};
    } catch (e) {
      print('[User.fromSnapshot] Exception building user from snapshot');
      print(e);
    }
  }

}
```

This is the stats data Map in Firestore:
[image: stats map]

Comment: That's a weird behavior, as you said stateless widgets calls build method only once, unless an interested value (Provider) force it to rebuild, do you call or change the firebaseUser or User provider when changing tabs?

Comment: Not at all. And if I change anything in Firebase, the affected widgets rebuild correctly with new data

Comment: This is a theory because I cannot see how is the User model built or how do you emit new values through the stream but if you say the user is incomplete perhaps you're using the same user model from the previous emmited value and changing its properties? If thats the case StreamProvider won't update its listeners because it checks in updateShouldNotify if the previous and new value are the same object ( == operation)

Comment: I will add this to the question. The model comes from Firebase and the object is created new every time. Also updateShouldNotify = (,_) => true

Comment: Have you tried checking while in debug mode (a breakpoint in provider.of to check the user model), I don't know if you're relying only in the print or if it's truncating the stats because of its length

Comment: Yeah, I am always debugging. But I also know the data is incomplete, not from the prints but for the errors and widgets missing because of that data

Comment: 'The user.stats map has half of the key-value pairs that it has when accesing it through Provider.of some widgets above' this is what I find weird, are you saying that the Provider.of(context) in 2 different places have different data at the same time? Also in debugged have you checked the data coming from the stream before the provider?

Comment: Exactly, that is the case

Comment: unless some widget is not being rebuilt (maybe because it checks the StateElement is the same) maybe you should try filling an issue in the provider git with a minimal reproduction sample

Comment: I think I might yeah. Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't see where you actually map the data. The User should have a .map function in it or you should create a function that maps the data for a user. Do you have this?@Jorge

Comment: @user10601874 I just added it to the question. I didnt consider it relevant (given that I create a new user with the stream)

Comment: maybe this will change something, but probably not. You can clean up your code a little by just returning this: usersCollection.document(uid).snapshots().map((s) => User.fromSnapshot(s)); instead of returning an object of stream.      somewhere you don't have an await or an async to wait for the data. It may be in the tab controller logic.

Comment: @Jorge I found the issue. Where you get the stats is the problem. It is not waiting on this data

Comment: @Jorge is 'stats' another collection inside that document or just an array of data?

Comment: @Jorge let me know how have that data set up in your firebase, and I can answer this question for you. post a screen shot of an example document

Comment: Hi @user10601874, thanks for your help. Stats is just a map inside a user document, from users collection, it is not another collection. I think you are right, it is not waiting for the whole data, but isn't that the way streams work? I mean, when I debug in higher level widgets I see two calls to build() because the stream returns an incomplete version of stats first. The problem is that for deeper widgets Provider.of only returns the incomplete object.

Comment: I just added a Firestore screenshot of the data. About the code change. How would I work with the StreamProvider if I didnt return a stream?

Comment: Little busy this weekend, but what you need to do is make a stats class of some sort then from that class do your mapping. It looks like it's null because there's no functionality to map the stats. then declare your class in the user class. Or you could take the easy way and declare your map differently. I think it's declared wrong for the implementation. It should be Map<String, dynamic> stats = Map<String, dynamic>();

Answer (score 0):

Although firebase does allow you to use a map as a type for you to use I don't think it is your best option in this case, as it seems to be confusing.

There are multiple solutions to your problem.

The best one I think is to make a collection side by side your users collection called "stats" and have the docid of each stat = the userid of the user with that stats, this makes querying easier for you in the future.

after this you can use the method you have already used to get the stats just like you get the users.

```
class Stat {
  String statid;
  int avg;
  int avg_score;
  List<int> last_day;
  int n_samples;
  int total_score;
  int words;

 



  Stat.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
     statid = snapshot.documentID,
     avg = snapshot.data['average'] ?? '',
     //rest of data
  }
        
}
```

perhaps the simple solution that you need is to change your map in the User class to this.

```
Map<String, dynamic> stats = Map<String, dynamic>();
```

remove the try and catch block, then you should be able to access your data like this `user.stats['average'];`

hope this helps, I will update my answer when I can actually put this to the test in an emulator, but if you try it and it works let me know.

Comment: Hi man, first of all, many thanks for your help. I tried first defining the Map as <String, dynamic> but didnt help. And then the thing about making a new collection sure will work but it does not actually solve the problem (I would prefer not to create new collections just because I cant make this work. I could also define each stats field as top level fields of the user object (and sure it will work as well) but we still don't know why the hell this is happening, do we?

Comment: I just dont know why Provider.of gives me the whole correct object in one place, but doesn't in a widget that is two steps down in the widget tree (where its incomplete).

Comment: because you need to declare the provider again in that widget @Jorge wherever you want the data to appear you need to re declare the provider in the widget or else it won't rebuild that widget.

Comment: @Jorge as far as the map goes it needs to be declared like so Map<String, dynamic>. This is how stats is set up in the database. It is not just Map stats it is Map<String, dynamic> stats. What is the new error after you make this change to stats?

Comment: 1) When you say 'declare the Provider' you mean calling Provider.of<User>(context) in the widget, dont you? because I do call that instruction wherever I need the object (within the build() method). In above widgets the whole object arrives (good) but in other nested widgets it arrives incomplete. This difference is what annoys me.

2) When I declared the Map as <String, dynamic> nothing happened. No error thrown, only that the map is still being returned as incomplete.

Comment: when you call snapshot.data you should do a cast. I.E. snapshot.data['stats'].cast<Map<String, dynamic>>(); you also need to handle this in case the user data you are getting doesn't have any data.

Comment: @Jorge I think I am wrong try declaring your map as Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Comment: also could you try getting a certain property for user.stats like user.stats["property"]

Comment: i am going to copy your project and run tests ill tell you the problem shortly.